# Populate a List View with Parse Objcets

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

My Main Activity has a button which redirects to ResterauntList Activity. I want to get a couple of Objects from my Parse Cloud, and want to add only the name to the ListView. This the code so far

```
package com.example.gastronomaapp;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener;

public class ResterauntList extends ActionBarActivity {
    String mValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);

        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        mValue = bdl.getString("Value");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);

        populateList(mValue);
    }

    private void populateList(String Value) {
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Restraunt");
                query.whereEqualTo("Location", Value);
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("name");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
            public void onLoading() {
                // Trigger any "loading" UI
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Not sure whats wrong, but the ListView never populates. My Parse Data Browser claims it has received requests though. Checked the Logcat, it claims the application may be doing too much work.Not really sure whats wrong.
(EDIT) Made a change as suggested in the comments. But now the list view has 2 entries but empty. I know there are 2 entries namely because they are clickable. Completely confused on what is wrong. Have edited the code too!
[This is my emulator, as you can see the line there are list view entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33O21.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting to call the `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` method. If I am not wrong, Parse queries are executed in background, right ? If so, then you need to call this method when the background thread is done.

Plus, as a suggestion, you can simplify your code as:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("ClassName");
query.whereEqualTo("KEY","VALUE");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){
  @Override
  public void done(List<ParseObject> dataFromServer, ParseException e){
      if( e == null ) { /** DO SOMETHING */ }
      else { /** DO SOMETHING ELSE */ }
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried adding the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to my code,seems to be stuck in the same error. Though not sure if Im doing it right,any direction on where in the code it should be added? And any other suggestions to sort the issue?

Comment: Try using the code snippet I provided. Move the dataset change in the `(e == null)` section

Comment: @Little Child - this is incorrect.  You do not need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the first load of the adapter.

Comment: @newbie - the code looks correct for what you are trying to do.  The message in the logcat that the application may be doing too much work should not cause a crash.  I'm a little suspicious about your database info, for example:  1) your query is for the "Restraunt" table - that is not the correct spelling of the word "Restaurant" - are you sure your code matches the table name in your database?  2)You queried where "Location" = "Value" - do you really have Restraunt objects in the table where the Location column has a value of "Value", exactly?

Comment: @user2163298 Oh i mispelled Restaurant when i made the table so that should be fine :P Removed the quotes from "Value" noticed that was a error. But a similar issue now, so i have edited the question.